# Can Mockito verify total number of method calls on a mocked Object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Mockito's `verify` can assert a certain number of interactions with a method on a mocked object occurred.

```
// Given
SomeService someService = mock(SomeService.class);

// When
someService.prepare();
someService.prepare();

// Then
verify(someService, times(2)).prepare(); // test passes
```

Sometimes it is useful in unit tests to know that the *total number of method invocations* on a mocked object has not changed.

This provides visibility (i.e. a failing test) when new method invocations are added.

Does Mockito provide this functionality?

In certain situations I'd want to call:

```
verify(someService, times(2));
```

..without getting an `UnfinishedVerificationException`:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock)...

Example of correct verification:
  verify(mock).doSomething()
```

Comment: Is this what `verifyNoMoreInteractions` is for?
Edit: seems like it is. Not quite the same, but it works for my purposes.

Comment: To me it is unclear what you means. Why do you want to use `verify(someService, times(2))` if you don't care about the exception? What do you want to test?

Comment: I want to assert that no additional method calls on the mocked object are performed. `verifyNoMoreInteractions` gives me effectively this, so long as I verify all the interactions I do expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no API for that at that time. You can **try** to code your own verifier code using [`MockingDetails.getInvocations`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getInvocations())

```
Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations()
```

Comment: Thanks, thought so. Glad I wasn't just missing something obvious!